# When should I exchange nouns to pronouns?Is there a obvious rule in it?

Tags: usage

**父亲**今年65岁了,**他**以前是一名律师。**父亲**的爱好是旅行，经常去旅行。

This sentence is strange to me.

First, **父亲**

Second,**他**

Third,**父亲**

I often hear that the English speakers avoid the duplications of noun.
Is it also in Chinese?

**父亲**的爱好是旅行 →　**他**的爱好是旅行 ( I thought it was right.)

I refer to a textbook and this is a solution for the quiz.
What is the purpose of this expression?

Why  dare the author to use **父亲** again?

I solved the quiz , often wrote "**他**的爱好是旅行" , checked the answer and it was not right.

When should I exchange nouns to pronouns?Is there obvious rules in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both English and Chinese are the same from this perspective. There isn't an obvious rule for it. Each author has his own way or style for this. The goal is to make your readers clear. I will write the sentence like:

> **父亲**今年65岁了, 以前是一名律师。**他**的爱好是旅行... ...

Or:

> **父亲**今年65岁了, 以前是一名律师, 爱好旅行 ... ...

Comment: The second one is confusing to me: Does "以前" apply to "爱好旅行"?

Comment: @tsh consider "父亲今年65岁了, [父亲]以前是一名律师, [父亲]爱好旅行 ... ..."

Comment: But why not reading it as “父亲今年六十五了, [父亲]以前是一名律师, [父亲以前]爱好旅行”?

Comment: @tsh is it more understandable to you when it's translated into English: My father is 65 this year, has been a lawyer before, and likes travelling. All I can tell is that the three clauses share the same subject, which is also common in English.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rules, but Chinese is also try to avoid duplication

父亲今年65岁了,他以前是一名律师。他的爱好是旅行，所以他经常去旅行. is totally OK.

Sometimes you can't, then try to avoid **continuous** duplication.

父亲今年65岁了,他以前是一名律师。父亲的爱好是旅行，所以他经常去旅行.

Author prefer synonym to eliminate duplication.

父亲今年65岁了,他以前是一名律师。**老爷子**的爱好是旅行，所以**他老人家**经常去旅行.

Comment: It's a little strange to use 老人家 and 老爷子 in the same sentence with the former being a term of respect and the latter a slangy term.